# How to protection source code Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Made site on Laravel + Vue.

How to protect the code from copying (PHP and VUE) when the project is on VPS hosting?

Interested in protecting the code in the resources folder.

Comment: The PHP code is "protected" since it runs on the server, assuming your server config is ok. Vue (or js) can't be hidden or encrypted, only obfuscated, otherwise it can't be interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Only the public folder should ever be visible. Remember you have the routes/web.php or routes/api.php files there and laravel will only ever resolve things in the routes file that are out of the public directory.

So so all you really need to do is follow the instructions on your vps to configure your server.

If you want to add an extra step, I use laravel forge, it basically does everything for you including deployment processing. You can hook it directly to your private repositories and basically commit right form your development environment to your server.

HTH